# Como adicionar HTTP-Tests do Laravel em um pacote PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, composer, phpunit

Estou criando um pacote em PHP, com o composer para quando finalizado ser publicado no [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).

Este pacote consiste de muitas requisições em outras APIs, no caso estou utilizando o [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Para realizar os testes no `phpunit` que ajude a testar a estrutura do JSON, encontrei [este](https://github.com/martin-helmich/phpunit-json-assert) pacote no github, porém mesmo em testes que retornam um JSON pequeno, o código é bem "chato" para fazer.

Estou um pouco mais familiarizado em projetos [Laravel](https://laravel.com/), logo gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma maneira de adicionar à este pacote uma dependência de desenvolvimento **apenas** para a parte de [HTTP-Tests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/http-tests#available-assertions) do Laravel, ou pelo menos toda a parte de testes, sem inserir mais do que isto.

Já realizei uma pesquisa na documentação do Laravel e um pouco no Stackoverflow, porém até o momento não encontrei nada. Se alguém souber, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Utilize a opção [**require-dev**](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) no `composer.json`

Comment: Certo, mas você sabe me dizer por favor o que eu adiciono ali dentro para adicionar apenas a parte de tests do Laravel?

Comment: `"require-dev": {"user/package": "version"}`. Dessa forma, o pacote será instalado apenas na versão de desenvolvimento.